Filebeat not refreshing files and pushes to Elastic
I need some help with strange behaviour of Filebeat vs Elastic.
I have AKS cluster (K8S 1.28.9) with stack: Elastic + Filebeat + Logstash (I have disabled it not to mess with Filebeat - it's not serving any reqs).
What I suffer from is that if I delete index in Elastic (after flush + clean) and restart Filebeat it updates all logs from certain period and than stops.
I have checked almost every possibility form internet but no success along with deletion of Logstash (output to Elastic can mess).
In Filebeat I can see that nasty part of log:

log.origin":{"file.name":"log/input.go","file.line":626},"message":"File
didn't change:

I can see 2 nodes have rules "dim" in Elastic cluster. I know that it is possible for node to have 3 rules but not recommended.
What is wrong with config?
Versions:
logstash:8.5.0
kibana:8.3.1
elasticsearch:8.3.1
AKS cluster: 1.28.9
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat-config
data:
  filebeat.yml: |
    filebeat.inputs:
        - type: log
          enabled: true
          paths:
            - /var/uat6-app/SL-LOG/*coresuite_sl-services-*.log
          scan_frequency: 1s  # Check for new log entries every 1 second
          close_inactive: 7200m   # Close files inactive for more than 5 days 
          clean_inactive: 45000m  # Remove state entries older than 30 days
          ignore_older: 43200m   # Ignore files older than 30 days
          close_eof: true # Filebeat will close the file as soon as it reaches the end of the file. If new data is appended to the file later, Filebeat will reopen the file and resume reading from where it left off.
          close_older: 1h
          
          
          multiline:
            pattern: '^\[\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'
            negate: true
            match: after

          processors:
            - dissect:
                tokenizer: '[%{timestamp}],%{log.level},[%{source}],%{requestToken},%{thread},%{hostName},%{clientIP},%{clientPort},[] %{message}'
                field: "message"
                target_prefix: "log"
                ignore_failure: true

            - dissect:
                when:
                  contains:
                    log.message: "PrimaryFilter - doFilter :"
                tokenizer: 'PrimaryFilter - doFilter : %{exception_message}'
                field: "log.message"
                target_prefix: "log"
                ignore_failure: true

            - add_fields:
                when:
                  not:
                    has_fields: ['log.clientIP']
                target: "log"
                fields:
                  clientIP: "unknown"

            - add_fields:
                when:
                  not:
                    has_fields: ['log.requestToken']
                target: "log"
                fields:
                  requestToken: "unknown"

            - add_fields:
                when:
                  not:
                    has_fields: ['log.clientPort']
                target: "log"
                fields:
                  clientPort: "unknown"

            - fingerprint:
                when:
                  has_fields: ["log.timestamp", "log.requestToken", "log.uri", "log.timeElapsed", "log.statusCode", "log.httpMethod", "log.hostName", "log.clientIP", "log.clientPort"]
                fields: ["log.timestamp", "log.requestToken", "log.uri", "log.timeElapsed", "log.statusCode", "log.httpMethod", "log.hostName", "log.clientIP", "log.clientPort"]
                target_field: "@metadata._id"
                method: "sha256"

        setup.ilm.overwrite: true
        setup.ilm.enabled: false
        setup.template.name: 'uat6'
        setup.template.pattern: 'uat6-app-*'
        setup.template.overwrite: true
        setup.template.enabled: false
          
        output.elasticsearch:
          hosts: ["${ES_HOSTS}"]
          username: "${ES_USER}"
          password: "${ES_PASSWORD}"
          index: "uat6-app-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
          ssl.verification_mode: "none"
          allow_older_versions: true
          document_id: "%{[@metadata][_id]}"



        logging.level: debug
        logging.selectors: ["*"]



Tldr;
I did try your config. But this behaviour for sure makes me think that the close_* options you set up are the culprits.
Could you disable them ?
